# Google Chrome doesn't ask to run flash content using swfobject.js

Tags: google-chrome, flash, swfobject

I have many old websites with partial flash contents which I init with swfobjects library. The problem is Chrome isn't even asking to allow flash, the pages runs as they don't have any flash objects. I'm using latest [Chrome Canary](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/canary.html) but same problem in latest Chrome too.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution on GitHub: https://github.com/swfobject/swfobject/issues/57

```
if(window.chrome)
    swfobject.ua.pv = [100, 0, 0];

swfobject.embedSWF(...);
```

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/43619497/revisions) to the question [Google Chrome doesn't ask to run flash content using swfobject.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43619497/google-chrome-doesnt-ask-to-run-flash-content-using-swfobject-js) by the OP [HasanG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/259881/hasang) under      CC BY-SA 3.0.</sub>